# report is working but can't able to get output of the report

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, report

i am able to call report successfull but i am not get the output of the report . reoprt must generate PDF. repport is not able to generate pdf .
code is

```
DECLARE 
rept REPORT_OBJECT; 
v_rep VARCHAR2(100); 
rep_status varchar2(200); 
BEGIN 

rept := find_report_object('EMP.RDF'); 

SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept ,REPORT_SERVER , 'repsrv'); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept,REPORT_DESTYPE,CACHE); 
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept,REPORT_DESFORMAT,' HTML');


v_rep := RUN_REPORT_OBJECT(rept); 
rep_status:=REPORT_OBJECT_STATUS(v_rep); 

WHILE rep_status in ('RUNNING','OPENING_REPORT','ENQUEUED') 
LOOP 
rep_status := report_object_status(v_rep); 
END LOOP; 
IF rep_status='FINISHED' THEN 
message('REPORT WAS CORRECTLY RUN'); 
ELSE 
message('REPORT FAILED WITH STATUS: '||rep_status); 
END IF;  
END;
```

plss help me

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to look

1)the find_report_object should have the report name you created in form builder

2)you need to use

```
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept, REPORT_FILENAME, 'C:\EMP.RDF');
```

where C:\EMP.RDF is the path in which the report should be generated

For complete example to do this and test please have a look at the below link

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2238519

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use `web.show_document` to get the output of the report. For example:

```
web.show_document('/reports/rwservlet/getjobid' || substr(v_rep,length('repsrv')+2) || '?server=' || 'repsrv','_blank');
```

Or, use the builtin `copy_report_object_output()` to copy the output to a file:

```
copy_report_object_output(v_rep, 'c:\myreport.pdf');
```

Also, if you want PDF output you need to change your DESFORMAT parameter to:

```
SET_REPORT_OBJECT_PROPERTY(rept,REPORT_DESFORMAT,'PDF');
```

Comment: @GirishRAcharya- Then why don't you mark it as an answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask